# appending to a list inside dictionary deletes previous values

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

so I want a  function where I read through a file, and creates an instance with every 'recipe'. I also want to create a dictionary, that contains another diciotnary, that points to a list. This is the format I am aiming for:

```
{cuisine:{course:[recipe_instance...]...}...}
```

But when I run the version below, I only get one item in every list, although there are more than one item in every list. I'm assuming that I am overwriting a previous value, but I am appending to the list, so i'm not sure if thats correct. Any help helps!

```
def read_file(filename):
    with open(filename,"r", encoding='utf-8') as filein:
        filein.readline()
        reader = csv.reader(filein)
        dic = {}

        for line in reader:
            srno = line[0]
            recipe_name = line[1]
            translated_recipe_name = line[2]
            ingredients = line[3]
            translated_ingredients = line[4]
            prep_time = line[5]
            cook_time = line[6]
            total_time = line[7]
            servings = line[8]
            cuisine = line[9]
            course = line[10]
            diet = line[11]
            translated_instructions = line[13]
            url = line[14]
            every_recipe = r.Recipe(srno, translated_recipe_name, translated_ingredients, prep_time, 
            cook_time, total_time, servings, cuisine, course, diet, translated_instructions, url)

            if cuisine not in dic:
                dic[cuisine] = {course:[every_recipe]}
            
            elif cuisine in dic:
                if course not in cuisine:
                    dic[cuisine][course] = [every_recipe]
                elif course in cuisine:
                    course.append(every_recipe)
                
    return dic
```

Comment: Isn't `course` a string?  How are you calling `.append` on it?  It looks like you want `dic[cuisine][course].append(every_recipe)`.

Comment: I think you need `if course not in dic[cuisine]:` and `elif course in dic[cuisine]:` and `dic[cuisine][course].append(every_recipe)`